# Infectious hemophilia

Tags: diseases, medicine, medical, blood

I want to know if the disease I invented is realistic or a total fiction.

Coagulopathies or bleeding disorders, like hemophilia, and Von Willebrand's syndrome, are diseases in which the blood's ability to coagulate is impaired.

But, is there an infectious disease that can be considered a coagulopathy?

I ask because I am writing a story with a disease caused by a virus that impairs coagulation.

Comment: [medicalsciences.se] might be a better fir, as it's a straight disease question without worldbuilding context.

Comment: Such diseases are called in general [haemorrhagic fevers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viral_hemorrhagic_fever); there are many. [Ebola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ebola_virus) is a very severe example, [epidemic haemorrhagic fever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hantavirus_hemorrhagic_fever_with_renal_syndrome) is a milder example.

Comment: Even COVID19 has effects on blood clotting. A lot of these things increase clotting, to the point that the body is flooded with micro-clots, and depletes clotting factors. Then the person bleeds uncontrollably.

Comment: Are you asking whether such a disease is realistic, or whether such a disease exists? The first is worldbuilding, the second isn't at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends on if you want hemophilia to be the only symptom.

A virus that selectively attacks megakaryocytes would cause this, as it would prevent platelets from being formed, and would cause pretty much no other symptoms.

If other symptoms are ok, any major damage to the liver can cause it too, as it would prevent clotting factors used by platelets from being produced.

Lastly, Ebola and other hemorrhagic fevers are essentially a transmissible hemophilia. They attack the tissues of the blood vessels and cause uncontrollable bleeding from pretty much every orifice, but they aren't limited to the blood vessels, and basically turn the body to mush by destroying cells that hold it together.  It's a very nasty way to go, but mercifully it also destroys the pain receptors.

Comment: You can imagine that Ebola would co-evolve with humans to become less deadly and more persistent, and basically become an infectious hemophilia.

Comment: @alamar It's true that the less deadly a virus is, the more infectious it tends to be, so that does fit well.

Comment: I was going to bring up Ebola and Marburg, so +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

### tPA, special delivery

[tPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissue_plasminogen_activator) is given to break up clots, as in myocardial infarction; but it can cause hemorrhage.  [Reteplase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reteplase) is a brand name of tPA that is 357 AA long, so it takes about 3x357 = 1071 nucleotides to code it.  [COVID-19](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severe_acute_respiratory_syndrome_coronavirus_2) has about 30000 nucleotides in its genome.  Now, I've been trying to cut down on the number of doomsday weapons I come up with a week, so I'm not going to delve into the details of how much extra RNA a COVID-X capsid could hold, or what parts of its current sequence might be dispensed with, or how to use its existing mechanisms to cut the tPA loose and release it from the cell membrane.  It's a research project.  Note: COVID-19 is *often* asymptomatic.  If you can cut out some sequence to weaken the virus and make it *always* asymptomatic, you'll have a lot of friends ... at least until they find out what you mean to do in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly feasible, there are both bacterial and non-bacterial diseases that can essentially cause or lead to coagulopathy. There are specific infections which can affect hemostasis, I strongly suggest researching exactly how you want it to go down, essentially.

Typically coagulopathy will present as one of many symptoms, or may be symptom of a symptom, so to speak.

I found these articles to be very helpful: https://academic.oup.com/jid/article/180/1/176/990517

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20614389/